# How to realize a math script

Tags: javascript

I ask for your help on making a script in JavaScript, given an array of integers (e.g. [10,4,8,5,9,5]) and a string of operators (e.g. `"*+-++"`) I should do the corresponding math operation ( example
`10*4`
`40+8`
`48-5`
`43+9`
`51+5`) and print the result of this operation in the console. All this with the proviso that the operators and integers can change and the code continue to work without changing it

```js
let operandi = [10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5];
let operazioni = "++-+";
let result = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < operandi.length; i++) {
  let operation = operazioni[i];
  let operand = operandi[i];
  if (operation === "+") {
    result += operand;
  } else if (operation === "+") {
    result -= operand;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You seem to have `operation === "+"` twice? Is the second supposed to be comparing against `"-"`?

Comment: Your `else if` condition is the same as your `if` condition.

Comment: You also have 6 numbers and 4 operators, and you haven't told us what you expect to happen in a scenario where there is no operator to include.

Comment: You might want to initially set `result = operandi[0]`.  Then, on each iteration, consider `operazioni[i]` and `operandi[i+1]`

Comment: You can follow [this](https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/evaluation-of-infix-expressions/) instruction to calculate math with operator precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, its just a case of starting with your first value `10` as being the initial value of `result`.

I've used the `spread operator` (`...`, "rest") to separate the first value from the "rest" of the values.

Then just expand your if statements for `"+"`, `"-"`, `"/"`, and `"*"`

```js
// Staring Array
const _operandi = [10,4,8,5,9,5]
// Get "starting value", 10
// Spread (...) remaining values
const [startingValue, ...operandi] = _operandi;
// Careful!!
// length of operazioni must be shorter than "_operandi"
const operazioni = "*+-++";
// Assign staring value
let result = startingValue;

// loop
for (let i = 0; i < operandi.length; i++) {
  let operation = operazioni[i];
  let operand = operandi[i];
  // result before
  console.log(i, result, operation, operand)
  // Operate based on value of operation
  if (operation === "+") {
    result += operand;
  } else if (operation === "-") {
    result -= operand;
  } else if (operation === "*") {
    result *= operand;
  } else if (operation === "/") {
    result /= operand;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: OP only had some formatting issues, they were close

Answer (score 1):

You can do that...

```js
const calculator = (()=>
  {
  const ope = 
    { '+':(a,b)=>a+b
    , '-':(a,b)=>a-b
    , '*':(a,b)=>a*b
    , '/':(a,b)=>a/b
    };
  return ( vals, calcs ) =>
    {
    if (( vals.length !== calcs.length +1 )  // ? bad length
      || (vals.some(isNaN))                  // ? bad number(s)
      || !/^[\+\-\*\/]+$/.test(calcs)        // ? bad operator(s)
      ) return undefined;

    return vals.reduce( (r,v,i) => ope[calcs[i-1]](r,v) )
    }
  })();


console.log( calculator( [10, 4,  8, 5, 9, 5], '*+-++' )) // 57
console.log( calculator( [10, 5, 10, 5,10, 5], '+++-'  )) // undefined
console.log( calculator( [10, 5,'x', 5,10, 5], '++-+-' )) // undefined
console.log( calculator( [10, 5, 10, 5,10, 5], '++Z+-' )) // undefined
console.log( calculator( [10, 5, 10, 5,10, 5], '++*+-' )) // 130
```